# How can you simulate "serverless" Cloud SQL?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

**Problem:** Cloud SQL instances run indefinitely and are monetarily expensive to host.

**Goal:** Save money while not compromising on database availability.

It has been almost four years and Google Cloud has not fulfilled this feature request that has already been implemented on AWS with their Aurora RDS.

Since it does not seem that on demand Cloud SQL that auto-scales to zero is coming any time soon, will the following strategy work?

1. Have instances of Cloud SQL, a Baby and a Papa. They follow the master/slave replica principle, with twist. The Baby
   instance is small with few vCPU's and low memory, it always runs, but
   does so cheaply. However, the Papa instance is expensive with high vCPU and high
   memory but runs only when needed.
2. To begin, only the Baby Cloud SQL instance is running so it is the master that accepts reads/writes. The Papa Cloud SQL instance is not running.
3. Since I am using standard app engine that
   will auto-scale to zero with no traffic, schedule a cron job that
   checks every 10 min if no app engine instances exists. In this case,
   the application has no traffic. If this is not the case, the Papa Cloud SQL instance is started. Once started, the Papa instance
   becomes the master that accepts reads/writes while the Baby instance
   becomes a slave replica capable of only reads.
4. If the cron job detects the app engine has zero instances running, this means there is no traffic. Thus, the Papa Cloud SQL instance is
   stopped and the Baby Cloud SQL replica is promoted to master and can accept reads/writes.
5. In this way, the expensive Papa instance runs on demand. If there is a traffic
   spike when the Papa instance is stopped or rebooting, the Baby
   instance will still be able to respond to requests.

This strategy ensures that the expensive Papa Cloud SQL instance only runs with traffic. **Is this Baby-Papa dynamic possible on Google Cloud?**

Comment: Interesting proposition, I wonder how long it would take for a "Daddy" instance to update its data when summoned.

Comment: If you plan on using this instance for at least a year, have you considered ```committed user discount``` - https://cloud.google.com/sql/cud? Would it be cheaper for you this strategy?

Comment: @NoCommandLine yes, event with the discount I need a cheaper solution

Comment: have you considered Cloud Datastore? It is a no-sql database but supports SQL like queries and transactions.

Comment: @dishantmakwana I have, but my application is already using SQL and refactoring code/migrating data is not viable

Comment: 1) Useful inventions happen when we do not accept the status quo. However, with managed services such as Cloud SQL, use them as designed. Your strategy will not work with Cloud SQL as this service is designed for enterprise-type applications and not serverless applications. If you want serverless SQL, use a serverless SQL service. Today you can mix and match cloud vendor offerings easily.

Comment: 2) SQL databases use memory to dramatically improve performance. Serverless SQL loses this feature which results in slower performance. When designing databases, there are many factors to consider beyond price.

Comment: @JohnHanley with regards to point 1, I understand Cloud SQL is not designed for what I just described, that does not mean that my strategy will not work. Perhaps the strategy is effective but Google has no interest in promoting it because it will cut their profits. With regards to point 2, I am not compromising on memory. Sure, the Baby instance will have low memory and low CPU but it will only have all db load when the Papa instance is asleep... this occurs only when my application has no traffic. Did you read the entirety of my post?

Comment: Why do you think your solution will work? Do you understand how replicas and standby instances operate? Review those features with Cloud SQL and then you will understand why your solution will not work. In regards to memory, review how SQL databases use memory to improve performance. Memory starved SQL databases perform poorly. Note: all of this is off-topic on Stackoverflow. Create a question that can be answered by facts and not opinions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud SQL has an [Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api) that can be used to manipulate your Cloud SQL instances in such a way. You could build pieces of what you are describing using [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler) to trigger a [Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions) which uses the API to start and stop instances, or even promote/demote them to master.

However, it's probably a bad idea. These operations can take several minutes to complete and would give you dramatic increases to cold start times for requests. Additionally, SQL servers prefer to be long running for a reason - they use resources to cache and optimize queries to improve performance. Start, stoping, and resizing instances can cause you to lose these benefits.

It's better to consider - do you actually need a relational database? If not, it's probably better to use something like [Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore), which is a serverless product.

If you determine that you do indeed need a relational database, can you optimize your use for a smaller Cloud SQL instance? Can you cache queries using [Memorystore](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore) or Firestore as listed above, or instead use the services I described above to export the results on a timed basis, which would be easier for your app to consume?

Would it be better to start and stop your Cloud SQL instance when there is no traffic? If you traffic is based around certain predictable times, you could schedule your instance to resize at the start and stop of these time periods.

Finally, if cost is really an option, you could run your own SQL server on a GCE instance. This means you have to do pretty much all of the management yourself (install, updates, maintenance, etc), but it would be cheaper.

All of these are probably much more functional solutions than trying to shoehorn non-serverless infrastructure to match a serverless workload.

Comment: I do need a RDB. I also have a complex application already built using SQL and I do not want to migrate away from SQL. Also I think you misread my strategy, I do not plan on resizing neither the Baby nor the Papa instance at any time. You are right, the Papa's cache would be cleared, but I can take the temporary decrease in performance if it saves me money. Why do you say cold start times would increase? The Baby instance always runs, the Papa won't receive queries until it has started fully.

Comment: Unless your traffic flow is has an unusually consistent velocity, you're likely going to outscale the "baby" instance before the "papa" instance is started up. Then you'll likely have a period of 1-2 minutes of downtime (or at least browntime) as the SQL instances are promoted/demoted and then requests to your App Engine instances (that require db access) will need to be notified of the change, and reestablish connections to the new primary before being able to execute write commands.

Comment: Are you sure that the aforementioned takes 1-2 minutes of downtime? If so, would you recommend having just one instance that resizes when necessary? Will resizing also produce 1-2 minutes of downtime?

Comment: You would need to 1. Start the L instance, 2. Set the L instance as a replica. 3. Wait for the replication to catch up 4. Promote the L instance to master. The longer the instance is down the longer it would take for it to catch up with replication lag. The exact promotion time would be dependent on how long all of that takes.

To resize, you'd have to shut down the instance, resize, start it back up. The exact time it takes is probably variable on the size of the instance.